# Is there a way to detect unused functions in C++/CLI?

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, dead-code

Is there a way to detect unused functions in C++/CLI? Seems like a basic thing.

May be any tool, inside or outside Visual Studio.

Comment: In a language that supports Reflection strongly, the word "unused" does not mean much.  You can never be sure.  There are dependency analysis tools out there, like NDepend, finding one that can handle C++/CLI is probably going to be tough shopping.

Answer (score 1):

[.Net Reflector](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) can do this. Use it to load any .Net assembly (doesn't matter what language), right-click the method you're interested in, and select "Analyze". It will show you what assemblies & classes the method uses, and which other methods call this one. If the "Used By" list is empty, then nothing call that method.

The analysis will include searching all the other assemblies loaded by .Net Reflector, so you can use it to load all of the assemblies for your application, and see if a public method in your DLL is ever called from your EXE.

Unfortunately, this is a manual operation, and requires you to select each individual method you're interested in.